# Check if user is logged in with Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, accounts, meteor-accounts

How can I determine layout depending on whether the user is logged in or not in Meteor?

I have tried

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.configure({
    layoutTemplate: Meteor.userId() ? "appLayout" : "startLayout",
  });
});
```

I get the error

```
Error: Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Meteor.user()` returns `undefined` if it's loading and `null` if it's logged out, same is true of `Meteor.userId()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(Meteor.userId(){
    layoutTemplate: "appLayout";
 }else{
    layoutTemplate: "startLayout";
 }
```

Did you try something like this ?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `this.userId`, as error mentioned `Meteor.user()` you can use in functions, otherwise use `Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId})` if you need any data from user collection.

Also, your iron-router structure is deprecated, [here](http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/) are new docs

Comment: `this.userId` is `undefined` even if I'm logged in. Is it my mapping or route structure which is deprecated? According to http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#creating-route-controllers the structure is still used. I don't know how to name each route if I'm using the other structure.

Comment: Controllers stay the same, but there is no map function anymore, and from what I know no functions at all for that matter(waitOn etc.), http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#route-parameters for creating each route and http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#named-routes for naming them

Comment: this.userId MIGHT be undefined because routes are created before Meteor.user() object, therefore this.userId is called before page even loads. Maybe try wrapping it up into function?